# Network/Bandwidth Compression

Tags: networking, compression, ipv4

I don't think it's possible, but is it possible to compress incoming network traffic at all to reduce bandwidth usage? If so, what are the common methods of doing this?

I'd like to compress traffic on a box running CentOS. I looked this up a bit but can only find tools relating to bandwidth monitoring.

Comment: How do you think compressing data that have already used your bandwidth will reduce the bandwidth? If you. bandwidth is 10 Mbps, and you receive data at that rate, then compress those data, you are still receiving the uncompressed data at 10 Mbps. Compressing it after the fact doesn't reduce the bandwidth used on the link to get the uncompressed data to you.

Comment: once the traffic has hit your machine, it is too late to compress to save on network bandwidth. If you were to do anything to compress it from your machine, it means it has already hit the kernel. If you want to do it from any other device on the network, then maybe, but you'd need a special appliance, but generally that means an appliance at both ends of the stream.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, I figured this would kind of be a stupid question, but I thought it was worth asking. Bandwidth is so expensive.

Comment: Mmmmm I guess an effective solution would be to get a box that has unmetered bandwidth, then send the data over to my colocated servers but compress it during the transfer

Comment: A link cannot have unlimited bandwidth (metering bandwidth has no meaning). There is going to be some type of bandwidth associated with any link. I think you may be confusing bandwidth (how many bits a link can accommodate per second) with data usage. Those are very different things.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, what I meant was a 1gbps link box, then compress traffic and send to my 100mbps colocated servers. They want like $3 for each additional mbps.

Comment: @SvenKahn, they might want it for each MB you send, usually data is metered in MB or GB, not how fast they travel. For instance, if I send 1mb per second, over 60 seconds I have sent 60mb (or 7.5MB). So even though I'm sending at a rate of 1mb per second, my total that is being metered is at 7.5MB after the first minute of use. On a 16mb line, I can send up to about 16 mb per second, and if I utilize the full pipe, after one minute I've sent 120MB, which is what is metered. In this case, compressed traffic can help as you're sending less over the pipe, but it must be done on the sending end